# ErrorException: Creating default object from empty value

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

I created table migrations in Laravel using `php artisan migrate:make`. When I tried to create the tables in the database, I got an error:

```
[ErrorException] 
Creating default object from empty value
```

What is this related to? No tables are created nor can I find any errors in my migrations.

I have 25 tables in the migrations folder, all look similar to this.

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateAddressesTable extends Migration {
    public function up() {
        Schema::create("addresses", function() {
            $table->engine = "InnoDB";

            $table->increments("id");
            $table->integer("user_id")->unsigned();

            $table->string("street");
            $table->string("city");
            $table->integer("postal_code")->unsigned();

            $table->foreign("user_id")->references("id")->on("users");

            $table->softDeletes();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    public function down() {
        Schema::dropIfExists("addresses");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you miss $table that you pass to the function.

Your schema create function needs to be in this style...

Schema::create('addresses', function(Blueprint $table)

Comment: Nice catch. I just happened to copy and paste the only faulty file here. It was the only one of the 25 files that had that missing. Thanks.